# Sorting icon issue with Jquery Datatable fixd header

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a follwoing script.

It enables the fixed header for a jquery datatable..

```
var alertion = 0;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).on('scroll', function() 
        {
            var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            var topDistance = $("#campaigns_list").offset().top;
            if(topDistance < scrollTop) 
            { 
                if($(".fixedHeader").length == 0)
                {
                    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(campaign_overview_table, {"offsetTop": 82},{ "top": true });
                }
                else
                {
                    $(".fixedHeader").not(':last-child').remove();  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $(".fixedHeader").remove();
            }
        });
});
```

The datatable is initialized by this way

```
campaign_overview_table = $("#campaigns_list").DataTable();
```

Now every thing runs fine, but when the fixed header appears and i click on a column to sort it, the sorting arrow doesn't change

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How does the makrup looks like? Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Does the arrow not change or does it not actually sort (i.e., arrow doesn't change, but the column still sorts)? Definitely will need to see some code to figure it out if it's the latter case.

Comment: arrow doesn't change, but the column sorts